# Default x-www-form-urlencoded content type for http request body in web services

Tags: xml, json, http, rest, soap

It may be REST or SOAP ....
why  should we use XML or JSON for request body for a web service
why dont we use simple  string like parameter=value&also=another in request body
( MIME TYPE: x-www-form-urlencoded )?

Actually it works on normal html form submission with php method ( MIME TYPE: x-www-form-urlencoded ) and it is default...

Doesnt it work on Web Services like REST ?
If it works... on what reason XML or JSON is used instead?
If reason regarding SOAP is that it uses HTTP+XML based protocol... lets skip it and consider only REST ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1), you can send any content type you like in an HTTP response as long as you provide the appropriate `Content-type` header.

The main benefit of JSON and XML over a plain query string is that they support hierarchies and complex data structures, e.g.:

```
{"cars":[{"manufacturer":"Ford"}, {"manufacturer":"GM"}]}
```

or

```
<cars>
   <car>
       <manufacturer>Ford</manufacturer>
   </car>
   <car>
       <manufacturer>GM</manufacturer>
   </car>
</cars>
```

These kinds of structures are usually very useful for webservices, and can't really be achieved with a plain query string.

Comment: Structure, yes, and also more complex syntax, like telling the difference between a string and a floating-point number, or knowing the encoding of a given string.